# Sitecore.FakeDB and Sitecore Content Search with facets

Tags: linq, unit-testing, sitecore, sitecore8, faceted-search

Following example from section "Refining search results by tagging based facets" from **[Sitecore Cookbook for Developers](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/sitecore-cookbook-developers)**.
However, i'm using [Sitecore.FakeDB](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb) to write unit tests against it.
I get this error when trying to Getresults()

> There is no method 'FacetOn' on type "Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.QueryableExtensions' that matches the specified arguments.

Here is the code

```
SearchResults<ArticleSrch> results = null;
       var query = searchContext.GetQueryable<ArticleSrch>()
                   .Where<ArticleSrch>(i =>(i.TemplateName!=null && i.TemplateName.ToString().Equals("Base Article")))
                   ;
       query = query.FacetOn(facet => facet.Tags); 
       results = query.GetResults();
       return results;
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: ca you try like on this page: https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Content-Search

Comment: Yes. I did use that content search technique from that section.My approach was a mixture of both, tagging technique from the book and content search from the Git wiki. However the real issue was with the "FacetOn" functionality of the IQueryable extension.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking around I found the answer.
Kevin Brechuhl of aquasonic, actually did something similar using Content Search with unit Testing.

[ContentSearchTest](https://gist.github.com/aquasonic/ac99844e1771ab3cce80)

So basically I was missing a Mock implementation of "FacetOn", similar to GetResults() at line 79. The interesting part was using LINQ to simulate facetting, which I simply did as

```
   public static IQueryable<TSource> FacetOn<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        return source.OrderBy(keySelector).AsQueryable();
    }
```